# Replacing a specific Unicode Character in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, replace, unicode-string

I'm using MS SQL Server Express 2012.

I'm having trouble removing the unicode character [U+02CC](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2cc/index.htm) (Decimal : 716) in the grid results.  The original text is 'λeˌβár'.

I tried it like this, it doesn't work:

```
SELECT ColumnTextWithUnicode, REPLACE(ColumnTextWithUnicode , 'ˌ','') 
FROM TableName
```

The column has Latin1_General_CI_AS collation and datatype is nvarchar. I tried changing the collation to something binary, but no success as well:

```
SELECT ColumnTextWithUnicode, REPLACE(ColumnTextWithUnicode collate Latin1_General_BIN, 'ˌ' collate Latin1_General_BIN,'') 
FROM  TableName
```

Or even using the NChar() function like:

```
SELECT ColumnTextWithUnicode, REPLACE(ColumnTextWithUnicode , NCHAR(716),'') 
FROM TableName
```

The results are 'λeˌβár' for all three.

But if I cast the column to varchar like:

```
SELECT ColumnTextWithUnicode, REPLACE(CAST(ColumnTextWithUnicode as varchar(100)), 'ˌ','') 
FROM TableName
```

the result becomes 'eßár', removing both the first character and 'ˌ'.

Any ideas to remove just the 'ˌ'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you just need to put N before string pattern too (if you want look for unicode char):

```
SELECT REPLACE (N'λeˌβár' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, N'ˌ', '')
```

Comment: This works for SQL strings where the string was assigned with a N prefix. For those columns where the data were inserted without the N prefix, this didn't worked.

Comment: Why is `COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN` necessary for this to work?  Leaving it out, in my case, causes it to fail.

Comment: Thanks, I just place N before unicode character/s and my problem solved.

Comment: In my own usage, the column was of type ntext, which is not allowed as an argument to REPLACE. I used convert to change to nvarchar(max) as my strings were all less than the max length.


`SELECT _..._   ,REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max),_columnName_) COLLATE 
 Latin1_General_BIN, N'�' , N'é')
 ,...
 FROM ...`

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine by following select query as we are getting U+FFFD � REPLACEMENT CHARACTER when we bulk inserting address filled from txt to sql.

```
select Address, REPLACE(Address COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,N'�',' ')  from #Temp
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour to learn how Stack Overflow works and read How to Ask on how to improve the quality of your question.