# SQL Server replace function has odd behavior with unicode modifier character

Tags: sql-server, unicode, utf-16

I have data with some half-width unicode characters in it (specifically U+FF9F) which seem to be interfering with the `replace` function:

```
select replace(convert(nvarchar(max), N'"'), N'"', N'""')
```

returns `""` as expected, but

```
select replace(convert(nvarchar(max), N'"ﾟ'), N'"', N'""')
```

returns the input string unaffected: `"ﾟ`. I believe this is due to SQL Server interpreting the two-character sequence as being distinct from `"` by itself.

Is there any way to get the `replace` function to replace that double-quotation character with two?

EDIT: This question is slightly different from the answer posed in [Replacing a specific Unicode Character in MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197784/replacing-a-specific-unicode-character-in-ms-sql-server). That question is asking about removing a half-width character, while this question is about modifying a character next to a half-width character. In both questions it was needed to set the collation to `Latin1_General_BIN`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing a specific Unicode Character in MS SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197784/replacing-a-specific-unicode-character-in-ms-sql-server)

Comment: `select replace(convert(nvarchar(max), N'"ﾟ') COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, N'"', N'""')` would fix the issue as stated in that link

Comment: What I run it I get two double quotes in both cases.  That seems correct to me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - may be your database is set with default collations to `COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN`?

Comment: thanks! the collation did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188046.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to work on Unicode characters.

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'"ﾟ') COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, N'"', N'""')
```